# Generate wav tone in PHP

Tags: php, wav

I would like to generate a sine tone in php. But constructing my wav I need to give the values in bytes. I don't know how to do that:

Here is the code I have:

```
$freqOfTone = 440;
$sampleRate = 44100;
$samplesCount = 80000;

$amplitude = 0.25 * 32768;
$w = 2 * pi() * $freqOfTone / $sampleRate;

//$dataArray = new


$text = "RIFF"
."80036"
."WAVE"
."fmt "
."16"
."1"
."1"
."44100"
."44100"
."1"
."8"
."data"
."80000";

for ($n = 0; $n < $samplesCount; $n++)
{
    $text .= (int)($amplitude *  sin($n * $w)); 
}


$myfile = fopen("sine.wav", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

fwrite($myfile, $text);

fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: You write the data in "text". A wave file is "binary".

Comment: What  @CommuSoft is trying to say is that you have to write the byte values, not the text content. For example, instead of writting `'44100'`, you have to write the bytes `0xAC44`.

Comment: @ Ismael Miguel -- Then why doesn't he uses the byte value for 80036 ?

Comment: @TheoZ It's already a numeric value.

Comment: ok then How to be shure that a value is on 2 bytes exactly as specified in the wav ?

Comment: @TheoZ Actually, never tried it. Probably you might need to add some padding bytes (usually `0x00`). I've never used `pack()`, but there must be a way to determine the format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you algorithm writes the numbers as text. Whereas a [`.wav`](http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html) file encodes the data binary.

You can use for instance `pack` to group data.

```
$freqOfTone = 440;
$sampleRate = 44100;
$samplesCount = 80000;

$amplitude = 0.25 * 32768;
$w = 2 * pi() * $freqOfTone / $sampleRate;

$samples = array();
for ($n = 0; $n < $samplesCount; $n++) {
    $samples[] = (int)($amplitude *  sin($n * $w));
}

$srate = 44100; //sample rate
$bps = 16; //bits per sample
$Bps = $bps/8; //bytes per sample /// I EDITED

$str = call_user_func_array("pack",
    array_merge(array("VVVVVvvVVvvVVv*"),
        array(//header
            0x46464952, //RIFF
            160038,      //File size
            0x45564157, //WAVE
            0x20746d66, //"fmt " (chunk)
            16, //chunk size
            1, //compression
            1, //nchannels
            $srate, //sample rate
            $Bps*$srate, //bytes/second
            $Bps, //block align
            $bps, //bits/sample
            0x61746164, //"data"
            160000 //chunk size
        ),
        $samples //data
    )
);
$myfile = fopen("sine.wav", "wb") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $str);
fclose($myfile);
```

This produces this [file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=74719922293793666696).

Note that you **can't** just reuse the above header. Some aspects were hardcoded that differ (like the size of the file, number of channels, bitrate, etc.). But if one reads the [documentation](http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html), one can easily modify the header accordingly.

Comment: Don't forget to also change `fopen("sine.wav", "w")` into `fopen("sine.wav", "w+b")` (notive the last parameter). This avoids that Windows translates `\r\n` (CRLF) into `\r` (CR).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: It can actually just be `fopen("sine.wav", "wb")`, the `+` isn't needed.

Comment: @RocketHazmat It isn't required, but it is always safe to use it. Just to guarantee that the file will be truncated.

Comment: @TheoZ: updated. But you don't seem to follow the format correctly. You first claim you will provide samples of `8` bit and later you provide `16`-bit numbers...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: That's not what the `+` does.  `w` means "writing", `w+` means "reading & writing".  Both truncate the file.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: @RocketHazmat Sorry about that. You are actually right, the `+` isn't needed at all. -.- damn memory...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: It's fine.  Good call on adding the `b`, though.  `wb` will help here :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat I don't think it is just an help. If he is experimenting, he probably is using a LAMP or XAMPP server. Most likely the later, since Windows is more widespread than Linux. Therefore, I believe it is a requirement (in this case) to have the `b` there.

Comment: @TheoZ: as argued before, currently the format you use isn't correct. I will try to update with the correct file format.

Comment: What is that `VVVVVvvVVvvvVVv` thing for?

Comment: @MightyPork: this specifies how to encode a number: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php. Thus the number of bytes, *little* versus *big-endian*, signed versus unsigned...

Comment: @CommuSoft It must be $Bps = $bps/8;

Comment: if i want to create 18hzk frequency sound , what should i do ??

Comment: modify `$freqOfTone` to `18000`, but chances are pretty high you won't hear anything. Most people are not capable of hearing such high frequencies. [You can test this yourself here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmKEhOS1QAo).