# PHP sin function goes up

Tags: php, audio, wav

I am generating a wav wobble tone in php with this function:

```
$samples = array();
$amplitude = 8192;
$sampleRate = 8000;
$samplesCount = 300000;


for ($n = 0; $n < $samplesCount; $n++) {


    $freqOfTone= 4*sin($n*0.00628)+440;

    $w = 2 * pi() * $freqOfTone / $sampleRate;
    $samples[$n] = (int)($amplitude *  sin($n * $w));



}
```

But the generated sound is not a constant wobble but goes up... (As you can hear there: [Sound Link](http://congruence.fr/stack.php)

Does anyone know why ?

Thank you

Comment: What's the point of adding `$t`? It's always 0

Comment: But I suspect the problem is with `$freqOfTone= 4*sin($n*0.001)+440;`

Comment: @Mark Baker Yes it's not needed. But I'm using it in other cases

Comment: Because counter $n keeps incrementing?

Comment: @BigScar Yes but sin function is supposed to be with a 2*Pi period?

Comment: What are the real parameters were used for linked sound sample? I mean $samplesCount and coefficients in $freqOfTone. It seems the coefficient before sin was greater, and coefficient inside sin() was lesser.

Comment: @Max Zuber I edited my question with samplesCount and the actual sin() inside (that changed indeed)

Comment: Just opened your sound in Audacity — it looks funny :-) I think, there are no errors in syntax, but something wrong with your math in tone generation.

Comment: When I use a constant like $freqOfTone= 440; it's the same sound.

 But if I use $freqOfTone= 4*sin($n*0.00628)+440; the wobble goes up and up but should stay the same

Comment: @Theo Z -- I updated my response. I'm pretty sure mathematically you have to account for the phase / amplitude creep, which is why its spiraling like crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't quite solve the problem the same way, but I spent some time playing with the weird math corners of the internet to help get the trig rust off. [This](http://basicsynth.com/index.php?page=fmsynth&WEBMGR=...3bf4c0509ba3e1b29dc79b64a) helped put it into perspective for me.

At anyrate, here's what I was playing around with (both amp and fm mod, I could screw with this for hours):

```
<?php   

$bps = 16; // bits/s
$Bps = $bps / 8; // byte/s
$duration = 30; // Seconds
$frequency = 440; // Hz
$amplitude = 8192;  

$samples = array();
$sampleRate = 44100;
$samplesCount = $sampleRate * $duration;    

for ($n = 0; $n <= $samplesCount; $n++)
{
    // Time
    $t = $n / $sampleRate;  

    // Freq Mod
    $mod = 0.1 * sin(2 * M_PI * $frequency * $t * 0.00628); 

    // Wave
    $w = $amplitude * sin(2 * M_PI * $frequency * ($t + $mod)); 

    // Amplitude Mod
    ($n / ($sampleRate / 10) % 2 == 0) ? $amplitude-- : $amplitude++;   

    $samples[] = (int)$w;
}   

$str = call_user_func_array("pack",
    array_merge(array("VVVVVvvVVvvVVv*"),
        array(// header
            0x46464952, // RIFF
            ($samplesCount * 2) + 44 - 8, // Filesize
            0x45564157, // WAVE
            0x20746d66, // "fmt " (chunk)
            16, // chunk size
            1, // compression (2 byte iteger)
            1, // nchannels
            $sampleRate, // sample rate
            $sampleRate * $Bps, //bytes/second
            $Bps, //block align
            $bps, //bits/sample
            0x61746164, //"data"
            $samplesCount * 2 // samples * compressed int
        ),
        $samples //data
    )
);  

// echo print_r($samples) . PHP_EOL;
$myfile = fopen("/tmp/sine.wav", "wb") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $str);
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: With the modulus it makes a cool effect but it is still going upeven with (%500). To make a tone wav from php go there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053226

Comment: Have you tried use modulus in both sin() arguments?

Comment: Yes, it works if I put ($n%1000+10000) in the 2 nd sin. But I don't undersatand why it's not working without: shouldn't it be 2pi periodic ?

Comment: np! Thanks for sharing the experiment, that was really a blast. I meant to throw this to you last night and forgot -- interesting way to look at it, and its open source so you can pick through the code for ideas http://newtonator.sourceforge.net/manual/ar01s02.html